# SQL query works, but SP as a whole does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I execute the FIRST and SECOND QUERYs through SQL Server Management Studio 2005 they work correctly and modify the correct data. However, when I try to execute the entire SP, I get no errors, but only FIRST actually modifies the data it is supposed to and SECOND does NOT.
I studied [THIS Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349545/mysql-query-runs-but-it-doesnt-work-in-sp) and think maybe there is confusion in my query too, but I'm not sure how to fix it as im not simply declaring a variable

NOTES:

*The only difference between this and code that worked completely fine is the use of the LEFT commands in FIRST and SECOND.

*While the FIRST query executes in <1, the Second query takes a little over a minute. I'm not sure if this may cause the problem.

*When I execute the entire SP it executes in <1 which shows it is skipping SECOND, but I have no idea why.

*No errors are returned

```
USE [abc]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bca]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.


------------------------FIRST------------------------
UPDATE p
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Transfer'
FROM cba as p
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE  = 'Delete' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM cba WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Add' AND FirstName = p.FirstName 
AND LastName = p.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = p.EmployeeEmailAddress AND EmployeeBirthdate = LEFT(p.EmployeeBirthdate, 4))> 0

------------------------SECOND-----------------------
UPDATE O
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify'
FROM cba as O
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Add' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM cba WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Transfer' AND FirstName = O.FirstName 
AND LastName = O.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = O.EmployeeEmailAddress AND LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4) = O.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0

END
```

EDIT: Original code without the LEFT commands

```
USE [abc]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[bca]    Script Date: 07/02/2013 10:14:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bca]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.

UPDATE p
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Transfer'
FROM cba as p
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE  = 'Delete' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM cba WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Add' AND FirstName = p.FirstName 
AND LastName = p.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = p.EmployeeEmailAddress AND EmployeeBirthdate = p.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0

UPDATE O
SET DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Modify'
FROM cba as O
WHERE DATAREVISIONTYPE = 'Add' AND
(SELECT COUNT([OriginalUserId]) FROM cba WHERE DataRevisionType = 'Transfer' AND FirstName = O.FirstName 
AND LastName = O.LastName AND EmployeeEmailAddress = O.EmployeeEmailAddress AND EmployeeBirthdate = O.EmployeeBirthdate)> 0


END
```

Comment: What datatype is `EmployeeBirthdate`?  I think you may be dealing with implicit type-casting.

Comment: Are you assuming that the second portion isn't running because the proc returns quickly, or did you verify that no data is being updated?

Comment: And why are you only returning the LEFT of the birthdate?

Comment: @MatBailie EmployeeBirthdate is nvarchar(250) the reason is the EmployeeBirthdate is mmdd and is part of a composite key for a 3rd party company. this leads to a ton of duplicates and so we put letters at the end of the mmdd (A,B,C,etc) to fix this (ie= 0206C). This is also the reason for the LEFT 4 characters of B-day (to avoid getting POSSIBLE letters at the end)

Comment: @StuartAinsworth See above comment and I verified that none of the data that SECOND should of updated was updated. The quicker speed just helps validate that it wasn't run (at least the same as if I execute it by itself) I unfortunately have no sort of debugging tool (cant install Profiler) to see where the problem is.

Comment: Have you changed the queries to be select statements in order to see what data should be updated?  Also your first statement about there being a difference in what you ran and what is in the SP is concerning.  Why is there a difference and why haven't you tried the exact statements that are in the proc?

Comment: @ChrisLively Yes, I have tried select, and SECOND returns nothing when executed as part of the entire SP. It just says Command completed successfully... I am an intern with little SQL experience that was asked to fix a bug. The bug being that new records that were compared to records that had a letter at the end of EmployeeBirthdate were not being recognized as duplicates. Hence the LEFT command which would skip over any letters at the end. My next job is to SET the new records fields that don't have letters equal to the old records fields.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I think the LEFT functionality is causing no rows to be returned.  You're effectively joining LEFT(p.EmployeeBirthdate, 4) (sample '0206') with Birthdate (sample '0206A').  No rows are being returned from the subquery, so no update is being performed.

Comment: I don't understand how this would make it work if I run the query by itself, but not work if it is run as part of the stored procedure. The only other idea I had for removing the POSSIBLE letter at the end was to "trim" for letters, which I'm not really sure how to do (but can research!) Forgive my lack of knowledge but Im not very familiar with SQL and all I really have to work with is a general programming knowledge and trying to mold the existing SQL statements to do what I want. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you mean by this comment "*The only difference between this and code that worked completely fine is the use of the LEFT commands in FIRST and SECOND."?  Is the query you are running IDENTICAL to the stored procedure?  That first comment seems to suggest it wouldn't.  Can you post the query that works?

Comment: Original working code has been attached. I meant that the only difference between the original code that worked fine, and the changes I made was the addition of LEFT commands.

Comment: Ah, then I think my suspicion is correct.  Looking at the code in your question, EmployeeBirthDate = LEFT(EmployeeBirthdate, 4) will return no rows to update if the values of EmployeeBirthdate are like '0206C'.  You need to use the LEFT function on both sides of the equivalency, or not at all.

Comment: Adding LEFT to both sides unfortunately does not fix the problem. It runs identical, ie, executes fine in SSMS when I execute just the queries, but the SECOND query still does not work if I execute as part of the SP. I appreciate the help so far though, any other ideas?

Comment: Instead of doing an UPDATE, rewrite them as a SELECT to see what is getting returned; in general, though, make sure that the code in the SP is the same as the query you are trying to do.  My gut is telling me that the statement you are writing doesn't line up, or the data doesn't.